# Sort TableView by distance from current location

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I have an SQL DB that contains Lat and Long info.  I have found my current location and been able to get the distance of each location from my current location.  I can get my tableview to show this distance, but know I want to sort that tableview so the closest are listed first.

My thought is I will need to add the distance to my SQL DB data, sort that some how and then display that info back to the tableview.

My thought is I would do all of this within my TableView.  Looking for guidance on how to do this and if I should be doing it in the tableview.

```
#import "TulsaMasterViewController.h"
#import "TulsaDetailViewController.h"
#import "Bars.h"
#import "BarDatabase.h"

@implementation TulsaMasterViewController

@synthesize barArray = _barArray;
@synthesize currentLat = _currentLat;


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
currentLat = newLocation;

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) {
    [lm stopUpdatingLocation];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Error obtaining location"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.barArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//Get the object from the array.
Bars *barObj = [self.barInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Set the name.
cell.textLabel.text = barObj.barName;

if (currentLat == nil) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?"];
}else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", cachedDist];
}

// Set up the cell
return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    TulsaDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.detailItem = [self.barArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.barArray = [BarDatabase database].barInfo;

lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
lm.delegate = self;
[lm startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

for (Bars *barObj in barArray) {
    NSString *strLat = barObj.Lat;
    NSString *strLong = barObj.Long;
    CLLocation *barLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[strLat doubleValue] longitude:[strLong doubleValue]];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLat distanceFromLocation:barLocation]/1000;

    [barArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cachedDist" ascending:YES];
    [barArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
}
```

For reference the rest of my code

Bars.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bars : NSObject {
    NSString *barName;
    NSString *barAddress;
    NSString *Lat;
    NSString *Long;
    NSString *cachedDist;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *barName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *barAddress;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Lat;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Long;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cachedDist;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address latitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude distance:(NSString *)distance;

@end
```

Bars.m

```
#import "Bars.h"

@implementation Bars

@synthesize barName = _barName;
@synthesize barAddress = _barAddress;
@synthesize Lat = _Lat;
@synthesize Long = _Long;
@synthesize cachedDist = _cachedDist;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address latitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude distance:(NSString *)distance;
{
if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.barName = name;
    self.barAddress = address;
    self.Lat = latitude;
    self.Long = longitude;
    self.cachedDist = distance;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

BarDatabase.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface BarDatabase : NSObject
{
    sqlite3 *_database;
}

+ (BarDatabase *)database;
- (NSMutableArray *)barInfo;

@end
```

BarDatabase.m

```
#import "BarDatabase.h"
#import "Bars.h"

@implementation BarDatabase

static BarDatabase *_database;

+ (BarDatabase *)database {
if (_database == nil) {
    _database = [[BarDatabase alloc] init];
}
return _database;
}

- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TulsaBars" 
                                                         ofType:@"sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
    }
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
sqlite3_close(_database);
}

- (NSMutableArray *)barInfo {

NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM TulsaBars";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) 
    == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *addressChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *latChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
        char *longChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9);
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
        NSString *address = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:addressChars];
        NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:latChars];
        NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:longChars];

        Bars *info = [[Bars alloc]
                      initWithName:name address:address latitude:latitude longitude:longitude];                        
        [retval addObject:info];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
return retval;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrm. There should be no sorting happening inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. It's too late in the game. If each cell is 1 bar, and the bars should be sorted by distance, I recommend achieving the sort in a lazy getter for your self.barInfo (if that's your list of bars).

I'm not sure what your model looks like, but if each bar object has a property for distance from whatever your reference point is, your sorting would look similar to what you have there.

This sorting would only happen the when the first cell is loaded (that's the "lazy" part) and then cached. So your cellForRowAtIndexPath: would just ask for the model object at it's indexPath's row, trusting that it is in the right order.

I'm not sure how much of this terminology you are familiar with, so feel free to ask clarifying questions and I will iterate on the answer.

EDIT after sharing more code:
I think you should add a @property to the bar called something like cachedDistance, and whenever you come onscreen (viewWillAppear), iterate over the bars and set their cached distance (using similar code to what you have in cellForRow...). Then implement a getter for self.barArray: `-(NSArray *)barArray` which essentially returns the barArray sorted using a sortDescriptor with the name of your cached distance property as it's key. This will simplify your cellForRow... code a lot.

You can then extend the logic to recalculate the distances when you get location updates, perhaps only if it is a certain distance from the previous.

Comment: property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *barName;
property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *barAddress;
property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Lat;
property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Long;

I don't have an actual distance field in my DB initially.  Under the cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm figuring out the distance as each row is loaded.  I figured that in order to keep the distance related to the correct row, I would need to add the distance to the array and sort under the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Setup
Bars.h/m Define Fields
BarDatabase.h/m Pull data
Location is in MasterViewController

Can send u code

Comment: You can edit your initial post with that, which will allow formatting and others will notice it :-)

Comment: I think I understand.  Let me digest and get back to you.

Comment: I have updated my code above to start doing what you said above, however I run into my first problem under viewWillAppear.  It doesn't like indexPath.  I tend to agree, but I'm not sure how to pull each row to do my distance calc.  Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: The logic in your viewWillAppear needs updating, it can't be the same as it was in cellForRow. There should be an iteration over your bars, setting each of their cached distances. Just carefully think through the process. In viewWillAppear, you just need to 'set up' the array, which involves loading the bars, then iterating over each of them (instead of trying to load one with index path) and calculating/setting the distance. Then sort the array and store it for later use in cellForRow...

Comment: Updated code again.  I'm still missing how to load my distance into my array.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: The property on bar objects should be of type CLLocationDistance, and right after you calculate the distance for the bar (inside the loop), set it on the bar. The, don't do the sorting inside the for loop, but after it. The loop exists purely to set each distance. Also, I'm not confident you are using all the correct property names, and I see evidence that you are having trouble understanding all the moving parts here. You are mutating an array while iterating it (BIG no-no), and you are not using the correct property accessors. I don't have time to spell it all out, think through each line.

Comment: I do appreciate the help.  I'm a very old basic and c guy, simple flow to the code.  Still learning the flow to Object-c and how to define everything.